# C# Windows forms DataGridViewComboBoxColumn foreign keys

Tags: winforms, postgresql, datagridview, combobox, foreign-key

Есть 3 таблицы: reader, street и city. Схема БД приведена ниже.

Вывожу содержимое таблицы reader в приложение. Я добился того, чтобы вместо id улицы, на которой живёт читатель, высвечивалось название этой улицы. Начал проделывать то же самое с городом, но из-за того, что город, в котором живёт читатель, это внешний ключ не из таблицы reader, возникли сложности. 
Список городов выводится, поменять и установить другой город получается (пока что без обновления в БД, только на уровне сеанса приложения), но соответствующий город не определяется. КомбоБоксы по-умолчанию пустые, а так быть не должно.

[image: В столбце "город" не определился город, в котором проживает конкретный читатель]

Как сделать так, чтобы города определялись?

```
//загружаем таблицу Читатели
            DGV_Reader.DataSource = DB_DataSet;
            DGV_Reader.DataMember = "reader";
            DGV_Reader.Columns["number"].ReadOnly = true;
            DGV_Reader.Columns["user_login"].ReadOnly = true;
            DGV_Reader.Columns["street"].Visible = false;
            DGV_Reader.Columns["number"].HeaderText = "читательский номер";
            DGV_Reader.Columns["passport"].HeaderText = "паспорт";
            DGV_Reader.Columns["telephone"].HeaderText = "телефон";
            DGV_Reader.Columns["house"].HeaderText = "номер дома";
            DGV_Reader.Columns["apartment"].HeaderText = "квартира";
            DGV_Reader.Columns["user_login"].HeaderText = "логин пользователя";
            DGV_Reader.Columns["name"].HeaderText = "ФИО";

            var DGVCBC_Reader_Street = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            DGVCBC_Reader_Street.DataSource = DB_DataSet.Tables["street"];
            DGVCBC_Reader_Street.DataPropertyName = "street";
            DGVCBC_Reader_Street.DisplayMember = "name";
            DGVCBC_Reader_Street.ValueMember = "id";
            DGVCBC_Reader_Street.HeaderText = "улица";
            DGV_Reader.Columns.Add(DGVCBC_Reader_Street);

            //недоработка где-то здесь:
            var DGVCBC_Reader_City = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            DGVCBC_Reader_City.DataSource = DB_DataSet.Tables["city"];
            DGVCBC_Reader_City.DataPropertyName = "city_id";
            DGVCBC_Reader_City.DisplayMember = "name";
            DGVCBC_Reader_City.ValueMember = "id"; 
            DGVCBC_Reader_City.HeaderText = "город";
            DGV_Reader.Columns.Add(DGVCBC_Reader_City);
```

[image: схема БД]

Comment: Почему комбобоксы? Если выбрать другую улицу, то номера дома и квартиры станут нерелевантными. Аналогично с городами.

Comment: В этом гриде данные только показываются или могут редактироваться прямо в нём?

Comment: Согласен, что станут не релевантными, но это уже другая проблема. Пусть пока будет так, на совести пользователя. Да, подразумевается, что редактировать можно (и даже нужно). Произойдёт подключение к БД, затем выполнится соответствующий запрос